# django if statement works for one but not the other

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use an if else statement in my views so when im signed in it says admin and when im logged out it client. It works for my queryset_list but not the name. Heres my code

```
def post_list(request):
  today = timezone.now().date()
  queryset_list = Post.objects.active()
  if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
      queryset_list = Post.objects.all()

  paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 8)
  page_request_var = 'page'
  page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
  try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
  template = "posts/post_list.html"
  name = "client"
  if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
    name = "admin"
  count = queryset_list.count()
  so = name
  hey = paginator.num_pages
  context = {
      "object_list": queryset,
      "name": so,
      "page_request_var": page_request_var,
      "today": today,
      "count": count,
      "paginator": paginator,
      "hey": hey
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that it works for **queryset**? Is there difference between *active* and *all*?

Comment: @m.antkowicz active shows all post that aren't posted in the future or in draft all shows all the posts no matter what

Comment: Why cant you just move the name assignment up in the other loop ? Another thing to look for is, the user you are logged in as might neither be staff, nor superuser..

Comment: I was rather asking about results od these queries - do you see difference on these lists? Are there any *all* items that arent *active*?

Comment: @m.antkowicz no the "all" and "active" works

Comment: What is being displayed when you use `name`? What isn't working about it?